# Angular component template global dynamic font

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am trying to allow the user to change the font, which should dynamically update the component.

As the component renders quite a few material components there are many 'Roboto' styles.

If I add this to the global styles.css

```
* {
    font-family: Lato !important;
  }
```

It does successfully override all of the other font styles .

But how to make that dynamic?
I tried an inline script tag in the template, but this gets stripped by angular (makes sense, other than this example).

I will try a dynamic stylesheet `link` tag, but that means creating a stylesheet for each font, a right pita. (we have 14 fonts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a class for each font, and apply the class using `[ngClass]`

For example, create a `serif` class, like so:

```
.serif * {
    font-family: serif !important;
}
```

Then apply it to your `AppComponent` with `ngClass`:

```
<div [ngClass]="fontClass">
```

Where the `fontClass` is a variable set in the ts file.